# Deploying Symfony2 project

Tags: php, symfony, netbeans, ubuntu-server

I developed symfony2 project on NetBeans 8.0.2 and XAMMP the project works fine on my windows PC ,so I upload all my project files to ubuntu server and execute the commands

```
chmod -R 777 app/logs
chmod -R 777 app/cache
```

then

```
php composer.phar install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

i ran (`php app/check.php`)  and its say your system is ready to run symfony project.

then T access http://example.com/myproject/web/config.php  and it says:

> Your configuration looks good to run Symfony.

but when I open: http://example.com/myproject/web/app.php its give me no response with

> 500 Internal Server Error.

and thanks in advance..

Comment: Look at the Symfony2 logs `app/logs/...` and server error logs, then copy-paste the error message here. You should also try `http://example.com/myproject/web/app_dev.php` to use the `dev` environment.

Comment: I enable app_dev.php and i got error:
RuntimeException in ClassCollectionLoader.php line 239:
Failed to write cache file "/var/www/html/myproject/app/cache/dev/classes.php".

Comment: Can you try again the `chmod -R 777 app/logs app/cache` command?

Comment: I try it and it work but when I use any app/console command its change the permissions

Comment: Try `php app/console cache:warmup --env=prod --no-debug` after `... cache:clear ...`.

Answer (score 0):

See logs server, and check the settings database **app/config/parameters.yml**